# Highcharts - on zoom start Y axis from 0

Tags: javascript, highcharts

After zooming in on the chart I would like the series to move down so they start from 0.

Let's say we have a following report:
http://jsfiddle.net/rathko/3c2GH/1/

Now when we zoom we see for example:

[image]

Instead I would like to have this serie Y axis to start from 0 rather than from ~17. On zoom-out it should go back to original but whenever user zooms-in it should start from 0 - meaning from all points the initial value should be deducted.

Is this possible with HighCharts?

I found the

```
startOnTick
```

but it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: I was able to achieve this with removing the first element value from all the data in series. Unfortunately that creates a problem. If we replace the timeseries while data is zooomed in on zoom out some of the original data points seems to be "forgotten" by the highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood, but when we zoom it yAxis begins from 0, but you would like to have from ie. 15, right? if yes you can catch afterSetExtremes event and call setExtremes to set customised range on axis. Second solution is using zoomType as 'xy'

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.events.afterSetExtremes